# How can resolve CertPathValidatorException

Tags: java, ssl

Below error message throwing when sent the API request. We have already configured the valid SSL Certificate of this domain, even no error message showing when open the browser.

SSL Cert provider: komodo

> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: CA key usage
>   check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set
>           at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:139)
>           at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:326)
>           at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178)
>           at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250)
>           at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:246)

How can i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the certification to environment.Below link will helpful if you deploy the your application in weblogic server.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs70/b2bsecur/keystore.htm